# Pycharm detects python rubber instead of python test template

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

When I run a test inside my tests folder via Idea, it always uses the Python template instead of the Python tests template. When I start all tests by selecting the tests folder, it even tries to start them as Django tests. I tried to change the template, but this it didn't help. The default test runner is set as Unittest.

So could anyone tell me how to choose Unitest as default test runner?

> [image: runner]

> [image: template]

I'm using Pycharm 2019.2.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to rename the tests from xyz_test.py to test_xyz.py